# PayPal API with PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, paypal, transactions

I have completed some transactions and receive notifications for all transactions but none show in my dashboard/transactions.

I am use paypal sandbox

One of my completed transaction is

```
array:27 [▼
  "TOKEN" => "EC-36N8470336681753Y"
  "SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED" => "false"
  "TIMESTAMP" => "2015-10-26T03:50:19Z"
  "CORRELATIONID" => "cc874cf6ad7c3"
  "ACK" => "Success"
  "VERSION" => "85.0"
  "BUILD" => "18308778"
  "INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED" => "false"
  "SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT" => "false"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID" => "39014269AD313580D"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE" => "cart"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE" => "instant"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME" => "2015-10-26T03:50:19Z"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT" => "150.00"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT" => "6.25"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_SETTLEAMT" => "61.28"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT" => "0.00"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE" => "BRL"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_EXCHANGERATE" => "0.426354"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS" => "Completed"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON" => "None"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE" => "None"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY" => "Eligible"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE" => "ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID" => "HG4W42MNN25E4"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE" => "0"
  "PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK" => "Success"
]
```

Can someone explain why dashboard not show the transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox/ page, this page only list REST API created transaction. You can't get class API created transaction, such as express checkout transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a solution, I need to login with my sandbox test account in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com there have all my transactions.

Comment: You are welcome !. Yes, this is the right way to get all transactions. :)